# Reading a ChunkedEncodingReadStream will always wait until complete body

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, stream, server-sent-events

I have the following (exemplary) code:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new("Bearer", apiKey);

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiUri) { Content = jsonContent };

var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

string line;

while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        continue;

    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

This code calls an API that uses [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) and therefore streams its data as it becomes available. By using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` the `client.SendAsync` line returns rather quickly - as it should, considering that receiving only the response headers should not take that long.

The problem with this code is the line with `reader.ReadLineAsync`. For some reason that line of code awaits the whole response's body to arrive before actually starting to read the line. Which is, of course, exactly what I **don't** want it to do, as it should instead read the lines as they arrive, one by one.

I tried this code using a `WebRequest` instead (which is deprecated by the way, and should no longer be used). I tried not using a reader, but read the stream byte by byte (even with a buffer size of 1 byte). But with all of these approaches, no luck. The first time the code tries to read from the stream, the whole response's body is awaited.

I know for sure that the response's content is a `ChunkedEncodingReadStream` as I debugged through it, which should be an indication that on the server-side streaming works as it should. While debugging, I could also observe that the private field `_chunkBytesRemaining` of the stream has a value of 0 before calling `ReadLineAsync` for the first time, and after that it has a value equal to the response body's size. And what, of course, mostly strikes the eye is the fact that the first call of `ReadLineAsync` takes a very long time (depending of the response body's size, e.g. 10 seconds), and every consecutive call takes less than a millisecond.

I searched the internet for solutions to this problem but no luck. Even third-party libraries that claim to provide a simple implementation for an SSE client use the exact same code and must therefore run into the same problem. I'm pretty much out at my wits' end, so I would appreciate it very much if someone here could share a solution or any further ideas on how to get this to work as desired.

Comment: The "long delay then all the data at once" is usually a sign of the server (or sometimes an intermediate gateway) buffering content, so not a client a problem. You could use curl to connect to the server, and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: You seem to be correct. Tried the same thing using curl and same result:  
The server takes a longer time (depending on the amount of data it'll return), seemingly to calculate the response, and only after that initial waiting time it starts sending event stream messages, but then "all at once", or to be more correct in an interval way less than 1ms.  
Really seems to have something to do with the server. Even though one should think OpenAI would get that to work in their chat completion API... ‍♂️

Comment: Okay, it seems to be a network problem. From outside the network I was testing my code in everything works fine.

Comment: We have the same issue: Client via HttpClient goes a WebApi, that talks to OpenAi and the first ~2 seconds are buffered. Not sure why, the WebApi returns an "async IAsyncEnumerable<string>" and in this method we disable the buffering (HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>()?.DisableBuffering();), but somehow the HttpClient waits ~1...2 seconds till the responses are read.